# T-SQL ALTER TABLE not being executed

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, alter-table

I'm having a weird problem. Code:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'columnName' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[xxx].[yyy]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [xxx].[yyy] ADD [columnName] [bit] NOT NULL Default 0
    update [xxx].[yyy] set [columnName] = 1
END
```

This fragment of SQL file fails with error stating that column `[columnName]` does not exist on line with update statement. When executed `ALTER TABLE` line seaprately in SSMS it executes correctly and then procedure works fine. What might be source of this issue?

Comment: The source of the issue is that T-SQL is *compiled* and when you try to compile the batch of SQL above, `[columnName]` does not yet exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to split it into a separate batch. Also, make the `ALTER` run inside an `EXEC`, otherwise you may have issues when the column *does* exist:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'columnName' and
              Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[xxx].[yyy]'))
BEGIN
    exec('ALTER TABLE [xxx].[yyy] ADD [columnName] [bit] NOT NULL Default 0')
END

GO

update [xxx].[yyy] set [columnName] = 1
```

The issue is that the (simplistic) T-SQL compiler tries to compile an entire *batch* in one go (batches are separated by `GO`<sup>1</sup>s). So it's tries to compile the `UPDATE` even before it's started *executing* any logic.

---

To make it conditional also:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'columnName' and
              Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[xxx].[yyy]'))
BEGIN
    exec('ALTER TABLE [xxx].[yyy] ADD [columnName] [bit] NOT NULL Default 0')
    exec('update [xxx].[yyy] set [columnName] = 1')
END
```

Where we're effectively using `exec` to again delay compilation until we know we want it to happen.

Incidentally, in this case I'd probably do it a third way:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'columnName' and
              Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[xxx].[yyy]'))
BEGIN
    exec('ALTER TABLE [xxx].[yyy] ADD [columnName] [bit] NOT NULL constraint DF_XXX Default 1')
    exec('ALTER TABLE xxx.yyy DROP CONSTRAINT DF_XXX')
    exec('ALTER TABLE xxx.yyy ADD CONSTRAINT DF_XXX DEFAULT (0) FOR columnName')
END
```

Because the first two methods will first update the entire table to have `0` in that column and *then* update the table a second time to set the value to `1` - whereas this final method should only have to update the existing rows once.

---

<sup>1</sup>Batches are split by client tools (such as SSMS) rather than SQL Server. `GO` is **not** a SQL Server statement/command, and also, worryingly, is only the *default* batch separator used by the tools. It's possibly to change from the default to something else, but I'd really recommend against it.

Comment: Is there a way to include update in the if statement for cleaner code? Sadly it must look like that because this is migration script and update should only be executed if column was added.